# What is this type 'literal' syntax in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, casting, postgresql-9.4

The [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) say a cast should look like...

```
expression::typename
typename(expression)
cast(expression as typename)
```

But this works:

```
select date '2015-06-20';
```

What is that syntax? Where is it documented?

Comment: It's an (AFAIK SQL-standard) way to specify the data type of an arbitrary literal. E.g. `INTEGER '42'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is typed constant - see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html section *4.1.2.7. Constants of Other Types*.

> A constant of an arbitrary type can be entered using any one of the following notations:
>
> ```
> type 'string'
> 'string'::type
> CAST ( 'string' AS type )
> ```